# Low response time when counting products in categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, count, ancestry

I need to render around 2500 categories (includes also nested categories - using ancestry gem) and products count in each of these categories.

Something like the following:

[image]

It takes very long time to load the page due to this. I iterate 5 lists (5 level categories in depth) and use the following code to count the products in a category (it always sum the products of the current category and also all nested ones):

```
<%= Product.includes(:category).where(:id => @filter_product_ids, categories: {:id => Category.find(root['id']).subtree_ids }).count %>
```

Is there any way how to speed this up? Right now I use only 200 categories and 10 000 products (expecting 500 000) and it takes 30seconds to load the page with only 10 000 products.

Thank you,
Miroslav

## SOLUTION

Cache counter : https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at the SQL that's being run against the database and create indexes for those columns. It looks like you're doing table scans on the products table; an index will speed things up considerably.

Comment: Thanks Andy. Actually I looked into console and saw lots of SQL queries, so I was looking for a way how to reduce it and fortunately for my purposes I found a great solution cache counter gem (https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture). Now it runs much faster.

Comment: Caching's definitely a good idea too; when you actually have to make the SQL query proper indexes will also increase performance.